# Private variables are being shared between instances of a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to use the "revealing module" pattern (constructor function version) as described in Javascript Patterns by Stefan Stoyanov.

I have a simple Point object that has two private variables, _x and _y.  When I try creating multiple instances of Point with differing _x and _y, all instances appear to point to the same object. They have the same values for the _x and _y variables.

Here's a link to my working jsFiddle example that demonstrates the exact problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/8dt2E/

So how do I ensure private variables are not shared, while still keeping them private (setting them on 'this' inside the constructor makes them directly accessible)?  I believe what I'm trying to do is possible, am I right?

FYI here's my code:

```
var Point = (function() {
    // Trying to use the revealing module pattern, as described in the book Javascript Patterns by Stoyan Stefanov'

    // Private.  Should only be accessible externally by public methods.
    var _x, _y;

    // Constructor
    var Constr = function(x, y) {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
    }

    var getX = function() {
        return _x;
    }
    var getY = function() {
        return _y;
    }

    var toString = function() {
        return getX() + ", " + getY();
    }

    // Prototype.  These are the public functions that are being "revealed"  
    Constr.prototype = {
        constructor: Point,
        getX: getX,
        getY: getY,
        toString: toString
    }

    return Constr;
})();

var pt1 = new Point(100, 100);
var pt2 = new Point(200, 200);
var pt3 = new Point(300, 300);
var pt4 = new Point(400, 400);

// Problem: Points all share the same private variables.  
alert("pt1: " + pt1);
alert("pt4: " + pt4);
```

Comment: What do you mean "why"? All your `Constr` instances point to the **same** variables - `_x` and `_y`. Put them inside of `Constr`

Comment: @Ian, updated question to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *private* variables are part of the IIFE, so they will be created once and then will be more or less *static* to each every other object instantiation. You need to make them properties of the `this` inside of the `Constr` object.

Alternatively, you could assign functions inside of the `Constr()` constructor function and use normal `var` variables. This has some disadvantages though...

- They are assigned on each function invocation (not once on the prototype)
- If you *do* assign them to the prototype, again you're doing it on each invocation
- It *can* be confusing to merge a lot of stuff in the constructor, I prefer them as a light function, but this is personal choice

The [revealing module pattern](http://blog.alexanderdickson.com/javascript-revealing-module-pattern) (disclaimer: my own blog) is designed to hide certain methods and properties from being used in the *outside world*, but this pattern doesn't work with instances of objects which need their own instance data.

Comment: I tried that, but then I can access _x and _y directly on the object.

Comment: @Ash Yep, that's JavaScript ;)

Comment: OK, so what pattern would you recommend to hide private variables and still use a modular approach?

Comment: @Ash If you want them to be tied to each instance, best you can do and have it readable is just make them properties. Prefix them with the underscore if you like.

Comment: @Ash - read [this article](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) to see how to make private member variables that are per object.  It uses a closure in the constructor function.  Similar in concept to what you're doing in your question, but it's per object because the constructor is invoked each time a new object is created.  And, then any methods that want to access the privates have to also be declared inside the constructor.

Comment: @alex You don't have to make them properties. Just declare them inside of `Constr`, right? The getter methods will also have to be declared on/inside `Constr` too though

Comment: @Ian Very true, and something that slipped my mind (I generally don't like adding any methods inside of the constructor). I will amend. Thanks!

Comment: @alex and others, thanks for the suggestions.  The final sentence in your answer is the essential point that I was missing (because I have not seen it anywhere before now about this pattern).  Maybe you should put it in bold?

Comment: @Ash I'm not a fan of bolding entire sentences. I might add a link too :)

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for the Crockford link.  It's a 2001 article but I should have known he'd have a concise and to the point article.

Comment: @Ash - though it's 2001, it is still THE way to have truly private instance variables (at least perhaps until ES6 comes out).

Comment: @alex, I've updated my answer with working code that gives me inaccessible private vars based on yours and others feedback.  The approach means functions are duplicated for every object instance (see answer) so not perfect.  Very happy to be corrected if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Ash You'd be better off leaving your question _as-is_ and posting an answer with your solution. Functions are duplicated, which is why I generally don't use it, but it's up to the developer :)

Comment: @alex, Good point. Question rolled back and added my own answer.

Comment: @Ash Sweet, +1 to you

Answer (score 2):

For others with a similar question; The updated code below now meets my main request of private variables being inaccessible externally.

This is possible because I define the functions and variables as locals inside the constructor. However it also means every instance has its own copy of the functions (inefficient use of memory).

A prototype approach would ensure only one copy of the functions are shared between instances, but that makes it impossible to have inaccessible private vars. Please correct me if any of this is wrong and I'll update this, I'd love to know if this is actually possible.

```
 var Point=(function() {

    // Constructor
    var Constr = function(x, y) {
        // Private
        var _x = x;
        var _y = y;

        var privateFunc=function(str) {

            alert('Private: ' + str + '  ' + _x);
        }

        // Public
        this.getX = function() {

            return _x;
        };

        this.getY = function() {
            return _y;
        };      

        this.toString = function() {
            return this.getX() + ", " + this.getY();
        };
    }


    // Prototype.  
    Constr.prototype = {
        constructor: Point
    }

    return Constr;
})();


var pt1 = new Point(100, 100);
var pt2 = new Point(200, 200);
var pt3 = new Point(300, 300);
var pt4 = new Point(400, 400);

alert("pt1: " + pt1);
alert("pt2: " + pt2);
alert("pt3.getX(): " + pt3.getX());
alert("pt4._y: " + pt4._y);
//alert(pt4.privateFunc('123'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want (access private variables with prototype functions) with a trick.

```
var Point = (function() {

// Private storage. Not accessible directly outside the closure
var reg = [];

// Constructor
var Constr = function(x, y) {
    var privates = {x:x, y:y};
    reg.push(privates);
    this._key = reg.length - 1;
}

var getX = function() {
    return reg[this._key].x;
}
var getY = function() {
    return reg[this._key].y;
}

var toString = function() {
    return this.getX() + ", " + this.getY();
}

Constr.prototype = {
    constructor: Point,
    getX: getX,
    getY: getY,
    toString: toString
}

return Constr;
})();

var pt1 = new Point(100, 100);
var pt2 = new Point(200, 200);
var pt3 = new Point(300, 300);
var pt4 = new Point(400, 400);

// Points all share the same accessors which look up the private registry via this._key
alert("pt1: " + pt1);
alert("pt4: " + pt4);
```

But there are drawbacks:

- The _key is still public and modifiable even though the registry isn't.
- Memory leakage can occur when your Point instances get garbage collected but their internals stay in memory.

Comment: that's an interesting approach, thanks.  Have you used this in a real application?  The registry would continually grow over time (the memory leak) so I guess it's not so good for long running aplications.

Comment: I thought it was an interesting problem to solve but I don't recommend actually doing this unless you're writing a framework. This should only be used on objects which have a clear lifecycle, where your framework can deal with the cleanup to remove the memory leak. For an object like point where you create many instances, I actually feel the reflexive use module pattern is an anti-pattern. Better to use object literals with prototype methods to conserve memory.